# How to create a Future from a Result containing a Future?

Tags: rust, future

Is it possible (logical?) to convert a result containing a future into a future that resolves to a result?

The following function is a bit broken, but hopefully makes what I am trying to achieve more clear:

```rust
use std::future::Future;

fn transpose<T,U,E>(result: Result<T,E>) -> impl Future<Output = Result<U, E>>
   where T: Future<Output = Result<U,E>> /* not sure if this is the correct trait bound */ {
   match result {
      Ok(inner) => /* a future that eventually resolves to a Result<U, E> */
      Err(error) => /* a future that immediately resolves to a Result<U, E>::Err(error) */
   }
}
```

To give some context: I found myself needing to do this after calling a `async` function from a closure passed to `Result::map`, so perhaps that was my first mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what one usually wants is to deal with the `Err` case immediately rather than waiting until the future is `.await`ed, so that might explain why a function like this doesn't already exist. However, if you do need it, it's pretty simple to write using `async` and `.await`:

```
fn transpose_flatten<T, U, E>(result: Result<T, E>) -> impl Future<Output = Result<U, E>>
where
    T: Future<Output = Result<U, E>>,
{
    async {                          // when polled,
        match result {
            Ok(good) => good.await,  // defer to the inner Future if it exists
            Err(bad) => Err(bad),    // otherwise return the error immediately
        }
    }
}
```

Or the same thing using `async fn` (which is not always quite the same thing, but in this case it seems to be):

```
async fn transpose_flatten<T, U, E>(result: Result<T, E>) -> Result<U, E>
where
    T: Future<Output = Result<U, E>>,
{
    match result {
        Ok(good) => good.await,
        Err(bad) => Err(bad),
    }
}
```

Since the `Err` value is returned from the enclosing `async` block or function, you can use `?` syntax to make it even shorter:

```
async fn transpose_flatten<T, U, E>(result: Result<T, E>) -> Result<U, E>
where
    T: Future<Output = Result<U, E>>,
{
    result?.await
}
```

I called this function `transpose_flatten` because to me `transpose` sounds like it should take a `Result<Future<Output = U>, _>`. This function flattens two layers of `Result` (the one passed to the function and the one returned from the future).

Comment: I think the OP wanted to *convert* a result to a future, and `.await`ing is actually resolving the future, which is more than a conversion.

Comment: @Ibraheem I think you're overlooking the `async` block. The `.await` does not run when `transpose_flatten` is called.

Comment: One thing that I thought would have been possible to avoid is the `Err(bad) => Err(bad)` line by using the right functional programming method. I guess this isn't the case?

Comment: @MichaelAllwright In general you can't necessarily avoid it. The obvious idea, `result.map(|good| good.await)`, doesn't work because `.await` is a control operator that affects the immediately enclosing `async` function, so you can't wrap it in a closure (much like `return`). However, since the result of `match` is returned anyway, you could use `?` to propagate the error value: `result?.await` does the same thing as the `match` here (but would not if it were not the last expression-statement of the function).

Comment: I added this variant to the answer. I will note that it doesn't strike me as especially "functional", but I think that's an unfruitful argument. If the code is concise, working and makes sense to you, who cares whether it's "functional programming" or not?

Answer (score 1):

If `result` is `Ok` you can simply return the inner future. However, if it is `Err`, then you have to construct a new future resolving to `Result<U, E>::Err(e)`. This means that you cannot return a generic `Future` because the two `match` arms return two distinct types. You have to return a trait object:

```rust
fn transpose<T, E: 'static, U: 'static>(result: Result<T, E>) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<U, E>>>
   where T: Future<Output = Result<U, E>> + 'static {
   match result {
      Ok(inner) => Box::new(inner),
      Err(error) => Box::new(async { Err(error) })
  }
}
```